# Going to VS Goes to

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Anderson):- Is your brother serious about taking job at fast food restaurant?

Bob):- I guess not. **He is going to college.**

Now my question is what does the highlighted sentence mean? Does it mean;

**Option A**: There he is, on his way to college. He refuses to work at restaurant.

OR

**Option B**: He goes to college. He studies. He doesn't want to work yet.

I think here should be **He goes to college** because I know about my own brother well and the other person doesn't and he is misunderstanding about my brother career's plans.

Comment: Not enough context.  For example, he could have just decided to start college but has not yet begun.  Because of this new plan, he can no longer start the restaurant job he was thinking of starting as an alternate job.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from that brief exchange what the circumstances are. It could mean either 'He intends to start a college course' or 'He is already attending college'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your brother serious about this fast-food job?  No, it is just for the summer until he goes to college in the fall.
-The job ends and college begins. You are certain he will start college in the fall.  --This is more about the exact time when the job ends and college begins.

Is your brother serious about this fast-food job?  No, it is just for the summer. He is going to college in the fall.
--This is more about how college starts in the fall, and continues.

Is your brother serious about this fast-food job?  No, it is just for the summer. He is going to go to college in the fall.
--You brother wants to go to college, and maybe has applied to a couple colleges, but it not completely certain.  It is a plan or wish

Is your brother serious about this fast-food job?  No, [he is going to college/he is in college] and needs some extra money.
-both are ongoing and both may continue for a certain amount of time

Answer (score 0):

Yupp here use of **he is going to colege** shows continuous tense nd here it not sounds good.
But use of present **he goes to college** used to show a habit nd upcoming condition of something..
Like **earth is revolving round the sun** is quite okk 
But **earth revolves around the sun**
Sounds perfect nd meaningful